# toggle header content on scroll without jquery

Tags: html, css, header, toggle

Is it possible to toggle the header when scrolling and reaching a diferent container? I only found solutions for fixed hights but not dynamically for individuell hights.

The three or more headers;

```
<a href="#home" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Apple </a>

<a href="#home" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Banana </a>

<a href="#home" class="w3-bar-item w3-button ">Stone </a>
```

And the different containers. So when scrolling down and reaching the Apple container, it should display apple in the header etc...

```
    <div class=" w3-center" id="Apple">
        blablablablablablablablablablablabla
    </div>


   <div class=" w3-center" id="Banana">
       blablabllablablablablablablablablablablabla
       lablablablablablablablablablablabl
       aablablablablablablablablabla
    </div>

   <div class=" w3-center" id="stone">
       blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablalablab
       lablablablablablablablablablalablablablablablablablabla
       blablablalablablablablablablablablabl
       ablablalablablablablablablablablablablabl
       alablablablablablablabla
  </div>
```

Comment: read this [link](https://medium.com/@mariusc23/hide-header-on-scroll-down-show-on-scroll-up-67bbaae9a78c).This may help you

Comment: Yes thank you but it doesnt really help me. I just want to change the text in the header for each different topic

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I know exactly what you want, but I think you're saying when you scroll down the page over the 'apple', 'banana' & 'stone' elements, you want those elements that are in the viewport to be represented in the header , all using vanilla js (not jquery)?

if that is the case, you need to do three things:

1. get elements you want to check
2. check to see if element is in viewport when scrolling
3. replace current header text with that of element in viewport's id name

To check if an element is in the viewport, I would set up a scroll event on the window, and then inside of the scroll event listener call this function with the element you want to check, it should look something like this:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    // returns a boolean value if the el is visible or not
    // in this case we test to see if the top of el is greater than 0px
    // and the bottom of the el is less than 1000px - you can adjust this
    // elem is the element to check;
    function isInViewport(elem) {
    var bounding = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
      bounding.top >= 0 &&
      bounding.bottom <= 1000
    );
};
```

This function will return a value of true or false depending on if the element is in the viewport, and based on that you can run a js function to change the innerHTML value to match the id of the element passed in to the isInViewport()

Credit to the isInViewport function here: https://gomakethings.com/how-to-test-if-an-element-is-in-the-viewport-with-vanilla-javascript/